# Docker compose showing networks as unsupported config for services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using `docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown` I have built two backend APIs that need to communicate with each other. Below is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '0.1'

services:

  user_api:
    build: ./users
    ports:
      - "5002:5000"
    command: bash start.sh
    networks:
      - api_network

  posts_api:
    build: ./posts
    links:
      - user_api
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    command: bash start.sh
    networks:
      - api_network

networks:
  api_network:
    driver: bridge
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for posts_api: 'networks'
Unsupported config option for user_api: 'networks'
```

I referred to the docker-compose documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

I cannot understand why it is showing unsupported. Please help.

Comment: I suspect the problem is `version: "0.1"`. The `version` element describes what version of the compose spec you're using; the current version is `3.9`, so you want either `version: "3"` or `version: "3.9"`.

Comment: @larsks Thank you so much it works!!

Comment: Also note that Compose provides a network named `default` for you (assuming you're using at least version 2 of the Compose file format) and you don't need `networks:` at all in most cases.  More details are in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks! I actually knew that, but I am currently learning docker-compose and trying out all sorts of commands, so I thought I will try and create my own network and work with it.